# Reverse play animation JS when mouseleave.

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, animation, bodymovin

I have a code that works great. I thing I don't like is that when mouseleave an animation stops sharp. That is not good. I got a couple ideas:

1. How make that 'stop' smoother and user-friendly?
2. How make 'reverse play' after mouseleave? (play reverse animation from breakdown point after mouseleave)

   ```
   animContainer = document.getElementById('bodymovin');

   var params = {
       container: animContainer,
       renderer: 'svg',
       loop: true,
       autoplay: true,
       autoplay:false,
       autoloadSegments: false,
       path: 'data.json'

   };

   var anim;

       anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(params);
       animContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", myScript1);
       animContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", myScript2);

   function myScript1(){

       anim.play();
   }

   function myScript2(){

       anim.stop();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Using the above example, this code works for me, though I can't help thinking there's a cleaner way to accomplish this...(will put a working pen up soon)

```
example1 = document.getElementById('example1');

var params = {
    container: example1,
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay:false,
    autoloadSegments: false,
    path: 'example1.json'
};

var anim;
    anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(params);
    example1.addEventListener("mouseenter", myScript1);
    example1.addEventListener("mouseleave", myScript2);

function myScript1(){
    bodymovin.setDirection(1);
    anim.play();
}

function myScript2(){
    bodymovin.setDirection(-1);
    anim.play();
};
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for posting here. Can you explain how and why it works? be sure to read [answer]

Answer (score -2):

Solved. Just put this code:

```
$('#bodymovin').hover(function(){

        bodymovin.setDirection(1);
        anim.play();

    }, function(){

        bodymovin.setDirection(-1);
        anim.play();
});
```

instead of:

```
animContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", myScript1);
animContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", myScript2);

function myScript1(){

anim.play();
}

function myScript2(){

anim.stop();
}
```

Comment: why not include the whole solution so that others visiting this page might learn something?! arg!

Comment: Why use jQuery for this? The first, plain vanilla JS, beats this answer.